# Use default intents with wit.ai API

Tags: api, token, wit.ai

I am developping an application using the wit.ai API and in the documentation (chapter "Why would I create an open app?"), it is written it is possible to use a copy of default intents but it doesn't work.

There is no example to explain how to do.

How can I use default intents please?

Regards

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide your codes, your intended outcome and exact issue which you are facing. In the current format it's not clear what is the issue that you are facing.

Comment: Sorry, below is my code :
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.wit.ai/message',
  data: {
    'q': 'Hello !',
    'access_token' : 'blabla'
  },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  method: 'GET',
  success: function(response) {
      console.log("success!", response);
  },
  error: function (error) {
      $('#theIntent').append(error);
  }
});

I use jQuery to test the API.

Comment: I would like to get a default intent for my sentence provided by the community as explain in the documentation.